# JavaScript to browse for folder and save full path into field

Tags: forms, pdf, path

In PDF form I would like to click a button, browse for folder and save the selected folder path into a text field (preferably with link if possible). Is it possible or not (probably for security reasons...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser based javascript has only sandboxed access to the filesystem for security reasons.
Don't waste your time; you'll not be able to get the selected folder.